# HttpClient - PostAsJson not sending null properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

While Im posting my object to another API with

```
HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, content)
```

My content sending with missing properties.

My content type is ***Dictionary < string, object >***

```
"limit": 10, 
"offset": 0,
"sort": null,
"order": null
```

When I post this object it is gone as

```
"limit": 10, 
"offset": 0,
```

Is it possible to post also null properties with *PostAsJson* method?

Comment: HttpClient doesn't have a PostAsJsonAsync method, it's an extension method added by some other package. Internally, it uses JSON.NET for serialization.  You *don't* have to use it to POST a JSON string, you can use Json.NET directly to convert the object to a string and control whether empty attributes are sent or not with the [NullValueHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PostAsJsonAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientExtensions.cs#L33) just calls `PostAsync` with a `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`. That formatter, or more it's base class `BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter`, creates an `JsonContractResolver` which is an `IContractResolver` from Json.Net and controlls if and how members are serialized to json. It calls a `IRequiredMemberSelector` from the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` to see if a member should [be serialized even it it's null](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/JsonContractResolver.cs#L39).

I think you best bet is to serialize the Dictionary with Json.Net and then send the string using the HttpClient. Like so:

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
HttpCLient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Comment: I think your linq line is for take properties except nulls but I need to send those properties unlike and I don't use a model generally.

Answer (score 4):

HttpClient doesn't have a `PostAsJsonAsync` method. This is [an extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientExtensions.cs#L87) added by the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package. It doesn't do anything particularly difficult, it uses Json.NET to serialize the `content` object into JSON. You can do the same with a couple of lines :

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

By default, Json.Net *does* serialize null properties. It will serialize all items in a dictionary, even if the item's value is `null`

You can ignore null properties with the [NullValueHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) property :

```
var settings=new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject,settings);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

This won't affect dictionaries. You'll have to filter out dictionary items that contain `null` values before serializing